# Integer (Euclidean) Division Notation in maths

Tags: number-theory, notation

I'm looking for a formal "operational" expression / definition in maths for the division between integers  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division) but I cannot find it.

Is this following correct?

Integer division: $ \quad a/b = 
\begin{cases}
\lfloor a/b\rfloor, \quad b>0\quad\\
\lceil a/b \rceil, \quad b<0
\end{cases}$

Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with just $\frac{a}{b}$?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. $a=kb+r,0\le r<|b|\implies a/b=k+r/b$ and we take floor or ceiling depending on whether $b$ is positive or negative (i.e. $r/b\in[0,1)$ or $(-1,0]$) respectively to make the term with $r$ disappear and isolate $k$, the quotient.